# What happens to private vars at the end of a sub routine?

Tags: perl

I have a script that reads of a global config file using Config::Tiny. Based on selection variable my script chooses a sub routine for either SQLite, MySQL or PgSQL.

Right now the config file is read at the top of the script and variables are set outside of the sub routines. But considering the MySQL vars have nothing to do with PgSQL or SQLite I wanted to set private vars in the sub routines. The only thing **I am wondering is what happens to the vars once the sub routine has ran its course?** Do they get removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared in subroutines will not exist after the subroutine returns.  Their memory will be released, and any referenced values will be eligible for garbage collection (assuming that nothing else references those values).

Comment: Lexical variables behave this way; package variables have different behavior.

Comment: Perfect! I just wanted to be sure when the script is running it was not going to hold on to the space used by the vars.

Comment: The memory won't be released back to the operating system until your process exits. The variables go away as far as perl is concerned but perl's memory size will still include the memory that was allocated until it exits.

Comment: This is just wrong.  lexical variables declared in subroutines will generally *not* have their memory released; it is retained so that it need not be allocated the next time the sub is called.  Referenced values will be freed, not eligible for gc - perl5 has no gc per se.

Comment: @ysth The freed memory is not associated with the subroutine at all and Perl certainly does have garbage collection.  The garbage collector marks chunks of memory as free.  The fact that on most OSes `perl` makes the decision to hold onto that memory, in the expectation of reusing it, doesn't mean it doesn't have a garbage collector.

Comment: "Freed" is a lot simpler to say and doesn't confuse people who come from languages that have garbage collection that runs independent of the executing code.  But leaving referenced values aside, lexicals are not even "freed".

Answer (score 5):

Since Perl 5 has no such thing as "private vars", I am going to assume you mean lexical variables declared with the [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) function.  At the end of the scope in which a lexical variable was declared, the reference count for that chunk of memory is decremented.  If this means the reference count goes to zero, then it gets garbage collected.  Since functions provide scope, then so long as you are not passing references to those variables to something that holds on to them, or using them in a [closure](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-variables-with-closures), then they should be garbage collected.

Comment: No, the sub itself acts as a reference and the lexical is not freed (though if there are any other references when leaving the sub, the sub is allocated a fresh lexical), though it is set to undef/empty, releasing any referenced data.

Comment: @ysth I don't understand where you think what you are saying is different from what I am saying.

Comment: If you set lexical to be a 1Gb string and the lexical goes out of scope, the 1Gb is not freed in any way, shape, or form.  It remains attached to that lexical and will be reused next time the lexical is in scope.